# Size of eigenvalues and diagonal dominance

Tags: linear-algebra

If $X$ is a diagonally dominant matrix and if $Y$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements of $X$, then how can one show that $ Y^{-1}(Y - X)$ has eigenvalues whose magnitudes are all strictly less than $1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply [Gerschgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem).